# How to approach implementing 'class Card' as required by Python textbook

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I'm currently working through John Zelle's Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science and hit a snag in Chapter 10. I'm having a conceptual issue in understanding the why and how of this exercise and require some assistance on how to approach the problem. The exercise asks me to create a program that displays *n* number of cards using a class named `Card` and requires the following methods. It should also be callable from within an app that generates *n* number of random cards:

1. `__init__(self, rank, suit):`
2. `getRank(self)`
3. `getSuite(self)`
4. `BJValue(self)`
5. `__str__(self)`

As ridiculously easy as this should be, I hit a wall trying to implement this class. I created a simple app that would generate a deck of 52 cards, prompts the user for the number of cards they want, and then populates the hand with those cards. I just can't see where I would benefit from a card specific class once the hand is generated. Here's my working code so far:

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suite):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suite = suite

    def getRank(self):
        return self.rank

    def getSuite(self):
        return self.suite

    def BJValue(self):
        if self.rank == 'Ace':
            return 1
        elif self.rank == 'Jack' or self.rank == 'Queen' or self.rank == 'King':
            return 10
        else:
        return int(self.rank)

    def __str__(self):
        return ('{0} of {1}'.format(self.rank, self.suite))


def shuffled_deck():
    deck = []
    for suite in ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']:
        for num in ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']:
            deck.append([num, suite])
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return deck


def main():
    deck = shuffled_deck()
    hand = []
    print('>> Card Generator v1 <<')
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input('Please enter the number of cards to display (1-7): '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input, please enter a number!\n')
        else:
            if n < 1 or n > 7:
                print('Please enter a number between 1-7!\n')
            else:
                break
    print('Your hand is:')
    for i in range(n):
        hand.append(deck[i])



main()
```

So once I've generated the hand of random *n* cards, I can't see how I would benefit from using the Card class, or even where to implement it. Since *n* is a random number between 1-7, I would need *n* number of variables to store each card object and then assign each variable to an instance of `Card`. I could show each card in the hand with `hand[i]` where i iterates through to `range(n)` without the need of a special `Card` class, but that's not what's expected from this project. I'm looking for advice on how to think about this issue so that I can make use of this required class.

Comment: Why would you need to have n variables? Just use a list for those random cards!

Comment: Why are you learning getters and setters in Python in 2013?

Comment: Do you mean `suit` rather than `suite`?

Comment: I understand your frustration as to _why_. For this example, it's easier to use simple suit & rank tuples, as opposed to objects. Objects show their strength once you've passed a certain threshold of complexity. For example, a text-based blackjack program would probably pass that threshold. If you're implementing a GUI for the game, objects are practically mandatory. But if a program is complex enough to warrant objects, it's too large to fit on one page. So the intro textbook can't show a good use case, and the reader is left wondering what the point is.

Comment: If I remember this book correctly, it actually goes on to explain why objects are useful, and build up a larger example, almost immediately after this step. And the reason it uses getters and setters is that it's actually meant to teach you programming in a way that you can take as many ideas as possible directly to Java, C++, JS, Ruby, whatever, rather than just Python (which I'm not sure is a great idea, but Guido endorses it, so what do I know?).

Comment: The project specifically calls for a user input specifying the total number of cards to instantiate. This project is intended to become graphical in the next lesson and so I am also trying to build it with that forethought in mind. I've written several apps, but never one where I was tasked with 'here's the outline for a specified object, build your code around it.' I needed some way to approach the problem and found myself deadlocked. Most of this feedback has been very insightful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the only thing you need to change in your code is to change the line:

```
deck.append([num, suite])
```

to

```
deck.append(Card(num, suite))
```

This makes the `deck` variable a list of 52 `Card` objects. That's useful because `Card` objects have some built-in functionality that a list of two items (like `[num, suite]`) doesn't.

---

Two examples: if you add the line

```
print hand
```

after your code, your current code would print something like

```
[["Jack", "Clubs"], ["9", "Spades"]]
```

while your new code would print

```
[Jack of Clubs, 9 of Spades]
```

(The line `print "\n".join(map(str, hand)))` might be closer to what you want in practice). You can also get the total blackjack value of your hand with the line:

```
sum(c.BJValue() for c in hand)
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is the concept I needed. And definitely thanks for the additional sum code. That was going to be the next issue I tackled after this one.

Comment: I made the change you suggested and then iterated through the hand:
`for card in hand: print(card.getRank())` and now I see the value of creating an object of each card. You never call the card by name after that, you call it by hand position. This was where my confusion lay, in deciding how to identify each card object in a callable way.

Answer (score 0):

I think any card class in python should have a __unicode__ method that uses u"\u2263" and so on--just for fun. I would also recommend decorating it with @functools.total_ordering along with the __eq__ and __gt__ methods so that card can be compared; moreover, the "sorted" built-in will then sort a list of card appropriately.